# Authentication Acting as Alert, Not as Window

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to automate testing, but I'm encountering issues when I try to code the login.  The authentication is acting as an alert in Firefox, not as a window, which means that I can't access the username and password fields.  How do I handle this so I can access the fields?

I'm using Selenium 3, Java 8 and Firefox 46 on a Linux virtual machine.  Unfortunately, I can't post any code per my company's policy.

Comment: As you can't paste code it's difficult for me to know what's actually happening. At first glance to me it sounds like Firefox asks for basic authentication? I mean it's not really part of the website your testing, is it?

Answer (score 2):

If you can try with firefox version 47+ as Selenium 3 is supported with later version from v47.
Here is the link for [reference](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3)

Hope the below solution can help you with Authentication Alert box -

using "selenium.security.UserAndPassword" library

```
UserAndPassword uAp = new UserAndPassword(userName, password);
driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(uAp);
```

OR

```
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(userName, password));
```

Reference StackExchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522434/how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window-using-selenium-webdriver)